# How to simulate an anchor click in angularjs after the href has been set?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, click

I'm trying to export to an excel file and I've gotten everything working except for the supposely most simple part of it; simulating an anchor click after the href to the file has been set.

I'm setting the attribute like this:

```
// This is inside a directive link function
scope.exportXLS() {

  var html = 'A long piece of html string generated from data';

  $('#export-xls-' + scope.graphId).attr('href', URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([html])));
}
```

Resulting in:

```
<li ng-click="exportXLS()">
  <a id="export-xls-0" class="eo-xls" download="exported-graph.xls" type="text/csv" href="blob:http%3A//localhost%3A3000/20b7d696-b1c2-41b3-a570-f7389ff3d2fb">Export to XLS</a>
</li>
```

Then I wait for the `$digest` cycle to finish running with the help of Angular's `$timeout` before calling `click()` as well as using `event.stopPropagation()` to prevent the anchor click from triggering `exportXLS()` resulting in infinite chaos:

```
$timeout(function() {
  $('#export-xls-' + scope.graphId).click(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation(); 
  });
});
```

But NOTHING happens.. The href is getting set but it's not downloading the file since the click doesn't appear to be working. I know `click()` isn't supposed to be used with anchors but I've seen so many answers saying that you can use it and it works really great etc. but not in this case.

Worth noting is that I'm on chrome and not firefox which I've heard has further issues with simulating clicks.

How can I simulate a click after the `href` attribute has been set?

Comment: Is the use of `scope` instead of `$scope` intended? What about `$timeout`?

Comment: If what The Head Rush said, doesn't help, try .trigger("click"); instead

Comment: @TheHeadRush scope is what you usually name the scope parameter which is in the link function. That's not where the problem lies. What about timeout what? Without it you get an error saying that a digest cycle is already in progress.

Comment: @RandoHinn Trigger doesn't work either.

Comment: I understand that there are legitimate reasons to use `scope` over `$scope`, which is why i asked that it was intended. I asked about `$timeout` to verify it was also being used inside the angular namespace - something that was not at all clear from your original post.

Comment: @TheHeadRush Updated question to make it more clear.